# How to deploy the silverlight web site on localhost (IIS 7)

Tags: iis-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am new to Silverlight, I have created an application having DLL Project, Silverlight project, and Silverlight.web project. Now I wanted to publish or deploy it in the IIS so that I can test the Silverlight web application. 
Can someone help me to deploy and publish silverlight web application?

Comment: If you are developing in VS, context menu of web project that hosts your silverlight app will have Publish... choice, publish wizard will take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click the Silverlight.Web project in Visual Studio.
Select the publish option.
Enter your web site configuration in "Publish Web" window.

If you are really new to IIS you can find a very basic setting to get started with in the "e.g." below the text boxes in the "Publish Web" window that opens up viz. "localhost" & "Default Web Site/MyApp". Add the Silverlight mime type (application/x-silverlight-app) to your IIS config. How to? > http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/

```
http://localhost/MyApp/SilverlightApplicationTestPage.aspx
```

should point you to your site.

Response to your extended issue from comment,
Since you now see login page, further steps
var canYouSeeAnySLonIIS = Is your login page made in SL?
try
{
    If (!canYouSeeAnySLonIIS)
{
        probably you won't have IIS setup for Silverlight apps. Add the silverlight mime type to your IIS. How to > http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/
    }
    else
{
        I don't have the specific solution to your problem but here since you can launch some SL from your IIS now, here is a tip that will help this and any other similar issue. You might want to try debugging the SL app inside IIS using VS. How?
    Launch your login(SL) page in IE (for simplicity). In vS, Tools > Attach to Process > search for iexplore.exe, make sure you select the one where the type column indicates "Silverlight, x86", this is the SL plugin sandbox process. Attach. Voila!
    A slight variation if you are using firefox, the process name will be plugin-container.exe
    }
}
finally
{
    Generic debugging tips > http://boxbinary.com/2010/04/debugging-silverlight-in-visual-studio-breakpoints-not-being-hit/
}

Comment: i have did the above stage now i am getting the SilverlightApplicationTestPage.aspx but now there is no database connectivity as i am DSN i have created DSN and using the DSN in web.config file when i run the project using VS2010 it is running. but when i publish and then run from the localhost it open the login page but no DB connectivity. can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: I updated my answer above yesterday, not sure if you got a notification for that