# Silverlight telerik radupload not working

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, file-upload, telerik

I'm using Telerik RadUpload for silverlight (I think it is 2013 release). Upload control works fine when I run my silverlight (VS2012, SL5) app in Visual Studio, I want to run my application outside Visual Studio, i.e. by clicking on html file generated by Visual Studio. This time Telerik Radupload control doesn't work and no file is uploaded, what is going wrong? I want to send this project to someone and he should be able to run project without Visual Studio (only running html file). Also I cannot upload my project on web.

How can I solve this issue?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

RadUpload has two parts that needs to be included (a client and a server side). The client side is executed entirely in the browser using the Silverlight platform. The server side requires a handler on the server for processing the files that are submitted from the client side. You will need to configure the server side before someone can upload files to it. Here is documentation that will help with that process:

http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radupload-getting-started.html#Configuring_the_server_side

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: I think my problem is that when I click on HTML file, no web-server is executed (unlike running app in Visual Studio), how can I run a web-server alongside my app?

Comment: thanks, can it be run automatically when my users click on HTML file?

Comment: Your site will be hosted in IIS. Users will simply navigate to a webpage that hosts your Silverlight app.

Comment: What do you mean by IIS hosted? when HTML file is clicked, SL app runs but I think there is no server, should I run a server separately?

Comment: The XAP file has to be hosted somewhere in order for users to browse to a HTML page and run your Silverlight App. Here is some more instructions on configuring IIS for SL apps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704133/how-to-deploy-the-silverlight-web-site-on-localhost-iis-7